# how to fetch query from mySql using first three alphabet of a word

Tags: php, mysql

I am making an android app to save data into mySql using php.Now after making table and save the data i want to fetch the data.But i want to fetch the data using first three or four letter .How can i do this plz help me.
my php code is.

```
    <?php

   require "loginConnect.php";

  $bookname =  $_GET['bookname'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM novels WHERE bookname LIKE '$bookname%'";
   $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $result = array();
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
  array_push($result,array(
                      "id"=>$row['id'],
                        "photo"=>$row['photo'],
            "bookname"=>$row['bookname'],
            "phoneNumber"=>$row['phoneNumber'],
            "price"=>$row['price'],
                             "discription"=>$row['discription'],
                             "address"=>$row['address'],
                             "publicationName"=>$row['publicationName'] 

             ));



       echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

       mysqli_close($con);

   ?>
```

Comment: Try :  $sql = "SELECT * FROM novels WHERE bookname LIKE %".$bookname."%'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and MySQL `LIKE`

`substr($bookname, 0, 4)` will give you first four characters.

And `like '$bookname%'` will give you all records having `bookname` starting from these four characters.

```
$bookname = substr($bookname, 0, 3);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM novels WHERE bookname LIKE '$bookname%'";
```

Comment: thank u very much.can u tell me how can i use to fetch perticular word from sentence.like bookname= 'The monk sink ' and if user seach monk than how can  i retrive whole row.Thanx in advanced

Comment: Use same query with `%` at both sides. Working sql: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM novels WHERE bookname LIKE '%$bookname%'";`

Comment: thank u again.. plz help me once again i m new in my sql and php.My question is like if there are two bookname start with 'cla' or having cla anyWhere how can i retrive both of them or any number of data having the same word.should i use for loop.

Comment: If you add `%` sign before and after, you can get book names having `cla` everywhere in the name.

Comment: but i m get only one of the result like if there are two name like calm or clay the only one of the row is retrive in json output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr` function to get first 3/4 characters of a word. Like this,

```
$characters = substr($bookname, 0, 4);
```

And use `LIKE` in SQL query to find results based on characters you got.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM novels WHERE bookname LIKE '$characters%'";
```

So your script will look like this.

```
<?php
   require "loginConnect.php";
  $bookname =  $_GET['bookname'];
  $characters = substr($bookname, 0, 4); 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM novels WHERE bookname LIKE '$characters%'";
   $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $result = array();
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
  array_push($result,array(
                      "id"=>$row['id'],
                        "photo"=>$row['photo'],
            "bookname"=>$row['bookname'],
            "phoneNumber"=>$row['phoneNumber'],
            "price"=>$row['price'],
                             "discription"=>$row['discription'],
                             "address"=>$row['address'],
                             "publicationName"=>$row['publicationName'] 

             ));
       echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
       mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if it helped you :)